# Asp.Net Core - Display string list values in textarea?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a list whose values ​​are taken from the database,I want each of these values ​​to be displayed in a line in textarea...

Controller :

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> AddOrEditPoll(Guid Id)
    {            
        var polloptionList = await _admin.GetQuestionsListByPollId(Id);
        PollViewModel model = new PollViewModel();    
        model.AnswerList = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in polloptionList)
        {
            model.AnswerList.Add(item.Answer);
        };
        return View(model);
    }
```

View :

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Answer</label>
        <textarea asp-for="AnswerList" class="form-control"></textarea>
    </div>
```

ّI want it to be displayed as follows:
[image]

Can you guide me if you have a good solution?

Comment: you sure you want textarea instead of radio button or checkbox or dropdown select? if yes how do you want to display them ? all the values in a single textbox combined? or each one of them in seperate text boxes?

Comment: @SyedMohammadFahimAbrar I just want it to be displayed in textarea,Because I want to edit them

Comment: Do you want them all in same text area? or a text area for each item?

Comment: @SyedMohammadFahimAbrar A textarea for all of them

Comment: you can map all the answers in a string first then bind that string to a text area in the razor. But u have to extract the list of strings from the model string on your own. i think a textarea for each answer should work better in case of codesmell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to replace `asp-for` with `id` and `name`,`asp-for` will set the value of textarea with `AnswerList`,and then convert `AnswerList` to `string`.Here is a demo:

Action:

```
public IActionResult AddOrEditPoll() {
            PollViewModel model = new PollViewModel();
            model.AnswerList = new List<string> { "answer1", "answer2" , "answer3" };
            return View(model);
        }
```

View:

```
 <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Answer</label>
            <textarea name="AnswerList" class="form-control" style="text-align:right">@string.Join("\n ", Model.AnswerList)</textarea>
        </div>
```

result:
[image]

Comment: It did not show anything and I want any value to be in a line

Comment: Does your polloptionList have values?

Comment: Showed but I want any value in a line is possible?

Comment: What do you mean `any value in a line`?Not each item?

Comment: So you want to split the answers with nullspace?If so,I have changed my answer to split answers with " ".

Comment: Please look at my questions again. I gave an example with a picture